# Values not updating on a view in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason, when I change the values from another view, it doesn't seem to update the values on the main view. The data is stored in an observable object and the array is published, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I am expecting that the values change to match the values in the data array (listed below).

Here is the how the data is stored

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct PlayerData: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var balance: Int
    let iconname: String
    var active: Bool
    let accentColor: Color
}

class PlayerDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var PlayerDataList: [PlayerData] = [
        PlayerData(id: 0, name: "Player1", balance: 1500, iconname: "car.side.fill", active: true, accentColor: .red),
        PlayerData(id: 1, name: "Player2", balance: 1500, iconname: "ferry.fill", active: true, accentColor: .green),
        PlayerData(id: 2, name: "Player3", balance: 1500, iconname: "airplane", active: true, accentColor: .green),
        PlayerData(id: 3, name: "Player4", balance: 1500, iconname: "fan.ceiling.fill", active: true, accentColor: .white)
    ]
}
```

Here is the main view code that displays the values

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainScreenView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel:PlayerDataViewModel
    @Binding var SelectedPlayerIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Game")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: FocusedBalanceView(SelectedPlayerIndex: 0, viewModel: PlayerDataViewModel())) {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Text("Values")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                            HStack {
                                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    ForEach(viewModel.PlayerDataList) { item in
                                        if(item.active == true) {
                                            Image(systemName: item.iconname)
                                                .foregroundColor(item.accentColor)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    ForEach(viewModel.PlayerDataList) { item in
                                        if(item.active == true) {
                                            Text("\(item.balance)")
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the code that changes the values in the main view

```
import SwiftUI

struct FocusedBalanceView: View {
    @State var SelectedPlayerIndex: Int
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlayerDataViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Balance")) {
                    Picker("Balance", selection: $SelectedPlayerIndex) {
                        Text("").tag("")
                        
                        ForEach(viewModel.PlayerDataList) { item in
                            if item.active == true {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(item.name)").tag("\(item.id)")
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "\(item.iconname)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 280)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Current Balance")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                
                Text("\(viewModel.PlayerDataList[SelectedPlayerIndex].balance)")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Actions")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.PlayerDataList[SelectedPlayerIndex].balance += 500
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "car")
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .background(.green)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.PlayerDataList[SelectedPlayerIndex].balance -= 500
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "dollarsign")
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .background(.red)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.PlayerDataList[SelectedPlayerIndex].balance -= 250
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .background(.blue)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is enough, if not then just tell me.

Comment: how do you change the values? please post the code that reproduces the issue, not just view rendering

Comment: Ok I edited the post to include how I change the values as well.

Comment: You are creating a *new instance* of the view model (`PlayerDataViewModel()`). You should pass the *same instance*

Comment: So should I use @Binding?

Comment: No. You should pass the instance of `PlayerDataViewModel` that you already have in your `View`. `FocusedBalanceView(SelectedPlayerIndex: 0, viewModel: viewModel)`

Comment: Ok I will try that and comment the result

Comment: So what would I change in the FocusedBalanceView

PS: I'm sorry for not knowing this stuff I am pretty beginner

Comment: I don't think you'll need to change anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're creating a completely new instance of `PlayerDataViewModel` in your `NavigationLink`. So, the data changed in that *new* view model isn't reflected in the rest of your UI. You should pass a reference to the instance that you already have:

```
FocusedBalanceView(SelectedPlayerIndex: 0, viewModel: viewModel)
```

Also, unrelated to you question, but you may want to consider adopting the standard conventions of naming in Swift, including using lowercase letters for the first character of parameters and variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow SwiftUI conventions the `View` struct is the view model and a store object holds the model structs, e.g.

```
class PlayerDataStore: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = PlayerDataStore()
    static var preview = PlayerDataStore(preview: true)

    ...
}

@main
struct PlayerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(PlayerDataStore.shared)
        }
    }
}

struct MainScreenView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: PlayerDataStore

...

struct MainScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainScreenView()
            .environmentObject(PlayerDataStore.preview)
    }
}
```

In this configuration you don't need to pass the store object into each `View` but can easily replace it when using previews for faster UI design.

Comment: Ok Thanks I’m pretty new to swift conventions so I didn’t know that.